# Change color of manual tqdm progress bar when finished in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, tqdm

I want to use a manual progress bar from tqdm in a Jupyter notebook with a nested loop. To have an overview over all iterations, I use a manual update of the progress bar as follows:

```
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm

a = range(100)
b = range(5)
pbar = tqdm(total=len(a)*len(b))

for a_ in a:
  for b_ in b:
    pbar.update(1)
    pbar.refresh()
```

[image: progress bar]

However, when the total number of iterations is reached (i.e., 100%), the color is still blue. But if I use something like `for i in trange(100): ...` , the progress bar turns green after finishing.

Can someone tell me how to achieve the same behavior for the manual progress bar? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think pbar.close() can do it.

```
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm

a = range(100)
b = range(5)
pbar = tqdm(total=len(a)*len(b))

for a_ in a:
  for b_ in b:
    pbar.update(1)
    pbar.refresh()
pbar.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this code on stackoverflow:

```
def progress_function(chunk, file_handling, bytes_remaining):
 '''
 function to show the progress of the download
 '''
 global filesize
 filesize=chunk.filesize
 current = ((filesize - bytes_remaining)/filesize)
 percent = ('{0:.1f}').format(current*100)
 progress = int(50*current)
 status = '█' * progress + '-' * (50 - progress)
```

You can edit this code to this:

```
def progress_function(chunk, file_handling, bytes_remaining):
  '''
  function to show the progress of the download
  '''
  global filesize
  filesize=chunk.filesize
  current = ((filesize - bytes_remaining)/filesize)
  percent = ('{0:.1f}').format(current*100)
  progress = int(50*current)
  status = '█' * progress + '-' * (50 - progress)
  #change the color of the progress bar to green when the download is complete
  if bytes_remaining == 0:
      status = '\033[92m' + status + '\033[0m'
  sys.stdout.write(' ↳ |{bar}| {percent}%\r'.format(bar=status, 
      percent=percent))
  sys.stdout.flush()
```

This will turn the progress bar to green when it is done.
I don't know whether it will help you or not. But, check it out anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above calling the method close() it's enough. Alternativelly you can  change the property colour. Like this:

```
import time
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm

total = 5
progress_bar = tqdm(total=total)
for i in range(total):
  progress_bar.update()
  time.sleep(1)

progress_bar.colour = "#00FF00"  # Bright Green
progress_bar.refresh()  # Optional
```